# I am getting error code 0x0000139F with VS2019 after a merge

Tags: c#, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019, project

This is my first question. I have looked for it but I have not seen results here matching my problem.

**The thing is...** I am working in a Azure Functions solution with C# using VS2019 as stated before. After finishing a PR, I have merged master with another branch of mine, in order to keep it up to date, in which I am working in another feature. The problem is that after the merge, I am unable to load some of my projects and all the info I am getting from VS is **"Error code 0x0000139F"**, which is not very helpful since it seems to be a generic code for projects that are not able to load.

I have tried removing these projects from my solution and reloading the whole solution but I have not been able to load them. I know that is not much, but with the info I have I can not think of more.

I would appreciate any insight and I have provided every piece of information I thought it could be useful, but I am happy to provide more info if someone thinks that it could help.

Comment: Take a look at the merge and look for any changes in the .csproj for the project that won't load? There may also be some more info in Visual Studio's Output window (check all the outputs in the drop down.)

Comment: Yeah, that was totally it. It was my bad because I thought that I finished the merge but I didn't, so when I went back to check the .csproj y realised. Thank you very much @phuzi !

P.S: do I have to do anythign in order to mark this question as answered by you? Thanks again!

Comment: Have added it as an answer ;o)

Comment: Great! Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sometimes happens during a bad merge. Take a look at it and look for any changes in the .csproj for the project that won't load?

There may also be some more info in Visual Studio's Output window (check all the outputs in the drop down.)